# helm image pull issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes, helm

i have a private registry for images, which works,,,, now i want to use that,,
my deployment.yaml

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "mychart.fullname" . }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "mychart.name" . }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}/ssh"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: "{{  .Values.imageCredentials }}"
```

and my values.yaml

replicaCount: 1

```
image:
  repository: registry.yoy.online
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
service:
  name: ssh
  type: NodePort
  externalPort: 31000
  internalPort: 2222
imageCredentials:
  registry: registry.yoy.online
  username: tesing
  password: tesing
```

but it fails,, im sure there is some mistake,